CS1061 Why can't I use "ToList"
UserTypeList = new List<UserTypeMV>();

foreach (var usertype in new DatabaseLayer.Pro_Database().UserTypeTables.ToList())
{
    UserTypeList.Add(new UserTypeMV()
                         { 
                             UserTypeID = usertype.UserTypeID, 
                             UserType = usertype.UserType 
                         });
}}

I got an error on .ToList(). I'm a newbie at this. Do you have any ideas on how I can fix it?
I tried to type it again but .ToList() is not in the dropdown list.

Why do you think you can call .ToList()? We don't know what class that is, we have no idea why it should work. Maybe if you tell is what UserTypeTables actually is we may be able to help.

You also dont need ToList here. You just want to enumerate all items in the database's User-Table(just deriving it from the names). If you want a list, you should store it in a variable before you enumerate it.

Yeah: ToLIst() is an extension method for IEnumerable or similar. Anything that can call ToList() will already work with a foreach loop without calling ToLIst(), and you can potentially save quite a bit of memory by avoiding materializing the sequence.

This line is suspect:
foreach (var usertype in new DatabaseLayer.Pro_Database().UserTypeTables.ToList())

If this is something like Entity Framework where "Pro_Database" is a DbContext then there are a few issues. When scoping a new instance of an object where "DatabaseLayer" is a namespace, "Pro_Database" is the class, and "UserTypeTables" is the collection/DbSet member at a minimum it should be declared like:
foreach (var usertype in (new DatabaseLayer.Pro_Database()).UserTypeTables.ToList())

where the parenthesis ensure we are "new-ing" an instance of the Pro_Database class, then accessing that instance's UserTypeTables member.
However, if we are dealing with something like EF's DbContext or another class that is Disposable (implements IDisposable) then you should instead be scoping that instance of the Pro_Database to ensure it is disposed correctly when you are done with it:

UserTypeList = new List<UserTypeMV>();
using var database = new DatabaseLayer.Pro_Database();

foreach (var usertype in database.UserTypeTables.ToList())
{
    UserTypeList.Add(new UserTypeMV()
                         { 
                             UserTypeID = usertype.UserTypeID, 
                             UserType = usertype.UserType 
                         });
}}

This ensures when your method ends, the "database" instance we new up will be disposed properly.
If this is EF you can simplify your code to avoid looping and loading the entire UserTypeTable entity by using .Select() to project the query directly into the view model:

using var database = new DatabaseLayer.Pro_Database();

UserTypeList = database.UserTypeTables
    .Select(ut => new UsertTypeVM
    {
        UserTypeID = usertype.UserTypeID, 
        UserType = usertype.UserType 
    }).ToList();


The benefit of projection is that in your original approach EF would fetch all columns of all rows in the UserTypeTable where you only need 2 columns as per this example. The Select projection approach will generate an SQL statement that only returns the required 2 columns and builds your list of view models without needing to loop through results and create them.
